# Adding input from textfield to database

Tags: php

I try to add datas which are taken from a textfile to my database with a php script, here is the script:

```
foreach($lines as $name){ 

    $bolunmus=explode(" ", $name);
        $add = false;
        if(!exist_in_db($bolunmus[0], $bolunmus[1], $bolunmus[2])){
        $add = mysql_query("
        INSERT INTO people(name, surname, age)
        VALUES('$bolunmus[0]', '$bolunmus[1]', '$bolunmus[2]');", $con);
        }
        else{
        echo (" could not write it.<br>");
    }
        if($add)
        echo $bolunmus[0]." ".$bolunmus[1]." ".$bolunmus[2]." Added to database.";

}
// this is my control function, which will return
// true if data already exist in database,
// else it will return false.
function exist_in_db($name, $surname, $age){
    $result = mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY id
    ");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            if($row['name']==$name && $row['surname']==$surname || $row['age']==$age){
            echo $row."could not write it.";
        return true;
        }else{
        return false;
        }
        }
}
?>
```

in fact, the problem is when I try to execute this script, it reads from textfile, and if that user does not exist, it adds, until here there is not any problem. But when I try to execute it again, it adds users with same output like "bla bla 0 is added to database." If I don't make any changes in text-file, I want it to control again, and if that user exists, do not add it, thanks everybody.

Comment: I hope you are prepared for people with my name: `PeeHaa ' or 1 = 1--Header: Injection\r\n<script>alert('yay!');</script>`

Comment: Or "PeeHaa von Lichtenstein"

Answer (score 0):

```
if($row['name']==$name && $row['surname']==$surname || $row['age']==$age)
  ^                                                ^
```

There should be a bracket here.

```
if(($row['name']==$name && $row['surname']==$surname) || $row['age']==$age)
```

To debug further, try `var_dump($bolunmus);`

Comment: that bracket was also a mistake, but the problem still exists :(